# SSIS error while running package using SQL job

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-job

I have SSIS package that import data from excel to SQL database 2012. the package runs fine and deliver what it supposed to do when I run it on visual studio. However when I try SQL job to run the package it keep giving me error massage below.

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error
>   code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft
>   Access Database Engine" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description:
>   "'Q:\Ledger\MajorGL.xlsx' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path
>   name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on
>   which the file resides.".

and the path is a valid path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure:

- Machine were SQL Server is installed has access to path: Q:\Ledger\
- User on which SSIS is running has access rights to the file MajorGL.xlsx

Comment: Yes it was a permission issue. now it works fine. My first mistake was I didn't provide the full name for Q:\Ledger\ path and I did. and the second and main problem was the service account that SQL server uses to run the package  didn't have permission to access the forlder in Q. I added the account in the folder security property with appropriate  permission.

Answer (score 0):

@zazzu-I think ,this is a password error with connection.Can u check with connections once again??

Just save the package and close the solution.Again open the solution and the package .Test the connections now.

Answer (score 0):

Drive Q sounds like a network drive, you will need to change your SQL job to run with a user that has permissions to that location.
Go to the section called USING PROXIES in [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/setting-up-your-sql-server-agent-correctly/) article and set up your package to use execute using this proxy.